# JS append </a> to <a>

Tags: javascript

I cannot append `</a>` to `<a>` (the second part isn't linked together) but can only use concatenation as showed below. How to solve this instead of using concatenation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>I'm A Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var b = '<a href="#">%data%',
            c = ' - %data%</a>',
            d = '1';

        // concatenation
        $("#a").append(b.replace('%data%', d) + c.replace('%data%', d));

        $("#a").append('<br>');

        // append
        $("#a").append(b.replace('%data%', d));
        $("#a").append(c.replace('%data%', d));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. The DOM operates on complete elements, not single tags.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with concatenation?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot append `</a>` to `<a>`, the second part isn't linked together

Yes. The DOM operates on complete elements, not single tags. When you add `<a>` without a closing tag, it fixes that for you so that you always have a valid tree.

> How to solve this instead of using concatenation?

There is nothing wrong with concatenation. Of course, there's a lot of things wrong with messing with HTML strings. Instead use

```
var d = '1';

$("#a").append($('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    text: '%data% - %data%'.replace(/%data%/g, d)
}), $('<br>'));
```

Comment: hey Bergi, really thanks for your answer, but why we need a 'g' here?

Comment: @earvinLi To make the regular expression global, and match all occurences of `%data%` not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the anchor tag inside variables. You can first create an anchor tag and append it to the div#a, and then append the contents of %data% to this newly created anchor tag

```
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var b = '%data%',
        c = '%data%',
        d = '1';

    $("#a").append("<a href='#' id='anchorTag'></a>");

    $("#anchorTag").append(b.replace('%data%', d));
    $("#anchorTag").append(c.replace('%data%', d));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Goontracker!